# PyQt5 button "clicked.connect()" not working when importing from class

Tags: pyqt

I am running a test for clicked.connect failing issue.

I want to wrap all the widgets in the `CentralWidget` to a class called `React`. When I call `React` in `CentralWidget`, widgets like `Button`, `self.writeLine` and `self.valLabel` will show up, but when I pressed the react `Button`, it's not functioning, which is to update `self.valLabel` according to `self.writeLine`.

A snap shot: [Buttom not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMgaX.png)

I suspect that

```
Button.clicked.connect(self.BottomPressedTest) # no function when pressed
```

is not doing what is supposed to do. But have no clue why this is happening.

The entire test code is shown below,

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


class CentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        panel = React(1).groupbox

        self.mainLayout.addWidget(panel, 0, 0)


class React(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, ch):
        self.value = 0
        self.groupbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox()

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.groupbox.setLayout(self.vbox)

        Button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('React')
        Button.clicked.connect(self.BottomPressedTest) # no function when pressed

        self.writeLine = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()#QLineEdit()
        self.writeLine.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 16))

        self.valLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.valLabel.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 20))
        self.valLabel.setText(f'React: {self.value}')

        self.vbox.addWidget(Button)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.valLabel)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.writeLine)

    def BottomPressedTest(self):
        print('React bottom pressed.')
        self.valLabel.setText(f'React: {self.writeLine.text()}')


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):


        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle(QtCore.QCoreApplication.applicationName())

        self.centralWidget = CentralWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)


class MainApplication(QtWidgets.QApplication):

    def __init__(self, argv: list):

        super(MainApplication, self).__init__(argv)
        self.mainWindow = MainWindow()
        self.mainWindow.resize(200,200) 
        self.mainWindow.raise_()
        self.mainWindow.show()

def main():

    application = MainApplication([])

    sys.exit(application.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Edit

I changed the first few line in `React` to

```
class React(QtWidgets.QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, ch):
        super().__init__()
        self.value = 0
        self.setStyleSheet('QGroupBox { color: white; border: 3px solid grey; }') #

        self.vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
```

, and then change `CentralWidget` to

```
class CentralWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CentralWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

        panel = React(1)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(panel)
```

Now the problem is solved. Many thanks to @[musicamante](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) and @[Passerby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17196203/passerby)

Comment: Remove `self.groupbox` from `React`, properly call `super().__init__()` after `def __init__`, use `self.setLayout(self.vbox)`, use `panel = React(1)` in `CentralWidget` and then `self.mainLayout.addWidget(panel)`.

Comment: Got it thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your React object is thrown away at the end of `CentralWidget.__init__`, with only the QGroupBox persisting. Save it in an attribute and your problem will be solved.

Note that your React object inherits from QGroupBox, but does not call its `__init__` method, instead creating a new QGroupBox as a member.